# Change script timeout on windows azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How is it possible to change the script timeout on a windows azure website?

Answer (score 5):

Given that you are not referring a specific language I assume it is ASP.NET. Either way, you have to change your `web.config` file and set the `httpRuntime`'s `executionTimeout` attribute to a desired value in seconds:

```
<httpRuntime  executionTimeout="300" />
```

If you are not coding in ASP.NET, just login to your web site with FTP, navigate to the site's root folder, open the web.config file and edit it. It must look something like (just a little more bloated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />    
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If there isn't file named `web.config` just create an XML file with the content above, name it `web.config` and place it in your site's root folder. That should do the trick for you.